# Node.JS/Nativescript. Как подождать пока асинхронная функция вернет ответ?

Tags: node.js, функции, if, callback, асинхронность

Вот в модуле есть функция, внутри нее уже метод вызывается из библиотеки, который с сервака информацию возвращает..

```
exports.login = function(user)
{    
    return auth.login(
        user.username,
        user.password,
        function (data) {
            console.dir(data);
            return true;
        },
        function(error){
            console.dir(error);
           return false;
        });
    }
```

Далее подключается этот модуль и вызывается эта функция в условии

```
if (ap.login(user)==true){..}
```

И так как это выполняется асинхронно, return не ждет пока данные с сервера придут и возвращается undefined сначала , а потом спустя время ответ..

Вопрос такой: Как переписать код чтобы заработало?

Обернуть в Promise это?

Или как то по-другому нужно делать?

Если можете, напишите код., правильный..для node.js v6.9.1

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Но но, а вот как переписать этот мой код, используя promises или callbacks?? я просто не понимаю там логики пока..их

Comment: Ну так возьмите и разберитесь ;)

Comment: Я пробую , помогайте :)

Comment: @LS2010 ваш вызов auth.login выглядит очень похоже на some.api.call из того вопроса.

Comment: я переписал так .., но чета не работает.. return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     auth.login(
     user.username
     user.password
    function (data) {
        //console.dir(data);
        resolve(true);
    },
    function(error){
        //console.dir(error);
       reject(false);
    });
  });

Comment: @LS2010, значит вы где-то ошиблись

Comment: смотри выше я написал.. ну данные то приходят

Comment: @LS2010, что-то мне подсказывает, что там есть ошибка

Comment: какая ?? ошибка .. там вроде просто все.. так же

Comment: @LS2010, если бы там не было ошибки, оно работало бы ;)

Comment: хмм) вы нашли ошибку?

Comment: Я вам написал правильный код в ответе. Зачем мне искать ошибки в вашем, неправильном?)

Comment: У меня node.js v6.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Как решить задачу с помощью функций обратного вызова и обещаний все итак знают. Я же покажу, как ее решить с помощью асинхронной магии ES2017.

Код модуля:

```
export async function login (user) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        auth.login(
            user.username,
            user.password,
            (data) => {resolve(true)},
            (error) => {resolve(false)}
        );
    });
}
```

Где-то в другом модуле:

```
import {login} from 'your_module';

const action = async () => {
    if (await login(user)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Эта "магия" работает только в седьмой версии, а она не LTS. Когда выпустят стабильную восьмую (к осени, видимо), тогда и будем колдовать.

Comment: Я это знаю. Правильный код для LTS есть в вопросе, чьим дубликатом является этот. Писать его еще и сюда - считаю лишней тратой времени и сил.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev так ведь про async и await там тоже есть...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну вот зачем вы портите педагогический момент?)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, к тому же, я отвечаю на прямой вопрос "_Если можете, напишите код., правильный.._" ;)